# Failover database connection for PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to modify my PHP database connection to include a failover connection to another server. I know this question has been asked, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is the code I have so far.

I know both the backup and prod server work, because I get a desired result from both servers configured for $serverA. It's the fail-over component that isn't working.

```
<?php

    $serverA = "mysiteA.dyndns.org:3306";
    $serverB = "mysiteB.no-ip.biz:3306";
    $user="myuser";
    $password="mypass";  
    $database = "mydb";

    $connection = mysql_connect($serverA,$user,$password);

    if (!($connection)) {
    $connection = mysql_connect($serverB,$user,$password); 
    };

    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);  

    $query = "SELECT listener_snapshot FROM listener_incr";
    $result = mysql_query($query);        

    $i = -60;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $dataset1[] = array($i,$row['listener_snapshot']);
        $i++;
    }
    $final = json_encode($dataset1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    echo $final;
?>
```

The PHP error file doesn't show anything but the failed first connection attempt. Edit: The first failure is by design in my test as I want it to fail over to the second server. As such I have killed MySQL on serverA.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. What error are you getting exactly, and is the condition to open the second connection ever fulfilled?

Comment: Did you bother checking `mysql_error()` to see why the connection failed? You're simply assuming that both servers are configured identically. And have no error handling except for that very first `if (!$connection)` bit.

Comment: As stated in the question I have tested both servers as the primary ($serverA). Both work fine. It's the php failover that is not working.

The first failed attempt is expected, as it's a controlled test of the backup (I killed the MySQL on serverA for this test).

Comment: Again - what error are you getting exactly, and is the condition to open the second connection (the `if (!$connection)` part) ever actually fulfilled?

Comment: @Pekka웃 this is the whole script. I wrote the original (which works) a while ago. Now I'm using examples from the web to add the fail-over component. It sounds like I'm missing something from my if statement. Can you help? I'm pretty green on PHP.

I get no error in my PHP error file. MySQL is irrelevant because I have tested both the connection and credentials as the primary, one after the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> <sub>And please in future, stop using `mysql_*` functions. You'd better start playing with PDO.</sub>

You can simply create an array, that contain all possible servers, and then iterate over it expecting success.

```
$serverA = "mysiteA.dyndns.org:3306"; 
$serverB = "mysiteb.no-ip.biz:3306"; 
$user="myuser"; 
$password="mypass"; 
$database = "mydatabase"; 

$servers = array(
  'A' => array(
    'username' => $user, 
    'password' => $password, 
    'host'     => $serverA
    ), 

   'B' => array(
    'username' => $user,
    'password' => $password,
    'host'     => $serverB 
));


function mysql_f_connect(array $servers) {
   foreach ($servers as $name => $array){
     $connection = @mysql_connect($array['host'], $array['username'], $array['password']);  
     // You can also store name of the server somewhere else
     if ($connection !== false) {
          return $connection;
     }
   }

   return false;
}
```

This function will return `FALSE` if connection to all servers is failed. Otherwise, it'd return a resource, that can be used for the rest, like `mysql_select_db()` etc

```
   $connection = mysql_f_connect($servers);

   if ($connection !== false) {
      // Well, you can start doing anything else
      $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);
   } else {
      // For debugging purposes:
      echo mysql_error();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, it might be a little complex for my solution, but definitely scalable. I will try it. One question, will this be efficient? i.e. will a second connection never get opened if the first works correctly?

Comment: Even after your edits It doesn't seem to work for me. The first connection fails, as expected. Then I get a very strange error. `PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Access denied for user 'myhostuser'@'myhostIP' (using password: YES) in /my/host/public_html/path/to/myphpfile.php on line 25`. Why is my script trying to connect to my web host at all? The two MySQL servers are remote.

Comment: Well, as you can see, it says that either first or second connection cannot be established, because of wrong `username/password/host` combination. In order not to show that error, you'd suppress it by putting `@` `before mysql_connect()`, so that it'd like `@mysql_connect()` inside that  `mysql_f_connect()` function.

Comment: Try to `var_dump($connection);` right after `$connection = mysql_f_connect($servers);` What does it say?

Comment: Same errors, I think there is a problem with the concat. As it's trying to connect to localhost with my web host username. Not the remote host with the credentials specified in the variable section.

Comment: Am I setting up the variables properly? `$serverA = "mysiteA.dyndns.org:3306";
    $serverB = "mysiteb.no-ip.biz:3306";
    $user="myuser";
    $password="mypass";  
    $database = "mydatabase";

    $servers = array(
       'A' => array(
          'username' => $user,
          'password' => $password,
          'host'     => $serverA
        ),
       'B' => array(
          'username' => $user,
          'password' => $password,
          'host'     => $serverB
        ),
        // The same for C, D, E etc
    );`

Comment: Jeez, my mistake, I typed `$array['user']` instead of `$array['username']`. See the update, it should work now

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. It's working now. I wonder... it takes 20 odd seconds to fail-over. Can you set the timeout on each failed attempt?

Comment: @square_eyes you can change the global MySQL connection timeout via `ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 60);` (60 is the default timeout in seconds, you can of course choose any number)